# I try to install teamviewer12 in ubuntu 16.4

Tags: 16.04, startup, services, teamviewer

I install `teamviewer_i386.deb` in my ubuntu 16.04 but when i run `teamviewer` it can't open but only show in title bar but.When i check system monitor show teamviewer is running `Teamviewer.exe` mode.I install a linux version download using 
`wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb`
 this command.How to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a **Debian package** without using ***APT***, the package may be corrupted due to dependency issues. open terminal (**CTRL + ALT + T**) and enter command below to fix this issue:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And the run TeamViewer again.